# Using phonegap audio api in gwt

Tags: gwt, jsni

I am wanting to use the phonegap audio api in GWT using JSNI.I cannot figure out how to code the methods in JSNI.

Wondering if anyone know of any tutorials.They javascript methods are really pretty simple.

http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_media_media.md.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it sounds like it would be something like this:

```
public final class Media extends JavaScriptObject {
  protected Media() {}

  public static native final Media newInstance(String src, Command command) /*-{
    var callback = function() { command.execute(); };
    return new Media(src, callback);
  }-*/;

  public native final void getCurrentPosition(AsyncCallback<String> command) /*-{
    var callback = function(position) { command.onSuccess('' + position); };
    this.getCurrentPosition(callback);
  }-*/;
  public native final void play() /*-{
    this.play();
  }-*/;
  //... more methods here
}
```

Usage:

```
Media m = Media.newInstance("http://www.example.com/src.mp3", new Command() {
  @Override
  public void execute() {
    // Code executed after Media is created.
  }
});
m.getCurrentPosition(new AsyncCallback<String>() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(String position) {
    Window.alert(position);
  }
});
m.play();
```

That's a rough sketch, if you know more about what the type being passed to the callback is you can do nicer things like have it be an `int` or another JS Overlay Type.

The API is kind of weird because everything is apparently asynchronous, but that's life.

Once you've gotten the hang of writing GWT JSNI bindings it's pretty straightforward.

If you end up getting further down this road, it would be awesome if you open-sourced your GWT wrapper library so other GWT developers could write some iPhone/Android apps.

Comment: Added example of the `play()` method, which is simplest since it doesn't take any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I just need the play method really.I am not quite as knowledgeable to do this correctly I guess.That code looks really foreign to me :-)

Still cannot accept your answer.The site does not recognize me it is strange.

I get the following error when trying to use the media in my onModuleLoad

The constructor TESTPHONEGAP.Media(String, new Command(){}) is undefined

```
Media m = new Media("test.mp3", new Command() {
           @Override
           public void execute() {

           }
         });
       m.play()
```

Using your class as an "inner class" in same file as my main onModuleLoad

Comment: This is weird the site is not recognizing me.I am trying to accept the above answer as well.

Comment: My sample was incorrect. The constructor is not correct, use `newInstance()` instead.

Comment: Please use comments, not new answers, to respond to my answer. Click "Add comment" at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I would but there is no comment option at the bottom of your answer sorry.

Comment: Still not working.Not sure what the problem is.Thanks for your help though

Comment: @james: You asked the question on an account created with a Google OpenID, but the account you answered with is registered through somewhere else.  I can merge them for you.  Do you want this account to be the one you keep, or the Google OpenID one?

Comment: Google OpenID please.And yes do merge them.Thanks